# talking to php with java

Tags: java, php, ajax, sockets

I have a php server that lets users create tasks to a database. Which are then queued, balanced, and executed by java on a different machine. I am trying to figure out how to tell the user that their task has been completed without having the user reload or otherwise leaving the page. I have thought about using sockets which i have not delved into with php so i am unfamiliar with. Another thought is i could have a js timer that ajaxs to see if the task was completed in the database. I am wondering if anyone has had some experience in this who could offer some insight into which would be better or if there is a better way.

Comment: js\jquery - AJAX db polling periodically, send an email ... really this is a question only you can answer and is off-topic here

Comment: Connect websocket not to PHP but to java backend. PHP is not a good idea as a websocket server. BTW: most popular websocket back-end is NODE.js